# Videos (.mp4) not loading in Safari when using Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, safari, html5-video, mp4, firebase-hosting

**Problem:**
I have a simple website running on Firebase Hosting. The tech stack is React / Typescript. My app plays a video when the user scrolls. Everything works as expected in Chrome but the video will not actually play in Safari.

I believe the issue has to do with how Firebase Hosting is sending this content. On the command line when I run "firebase serve --only hosting" videos will play within my app in Chrome but not in Safari. I think this might be due to Safari receiving a 200 status and not 206. Additionally, the video does not play if I run directly in another browser tab "http://localhost:5000/images/video.mp4".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your server MUST support range requests (206)

Comment: @ szatmary thanks for the confirmation, this was my suspicion. Do the good people at Google or anyone else know if it's possible to configure Firebase Hosting to support range requests, as this, unfortunately, does not seem to be an out of the box capability.

Comment: Still an issue in 2024.  Confirming what @szatmary says, you need _both_ the Range header and the 206 status.  I was able to add a Range headers to video file requests, however it's NOT possible to change a request's status using hosting rewrites.  Maybe possible using a Firebase Functions proxy, however sounds super slow.  I'm switching to a 3rd party CDN for video files unfortunately /: